# watch a dsf video file

Tags: video

i have a video file with extension .dsf, taken from a cctv surveillance camera
(i don't known model or producer of the appliance).

how i can watch it? suggest some free software (any os)

thank you

Comment: Pelco is one manufacturer using this format.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint you, but `.dsf` looks like it may be a sound file.

Have you tried [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html)? It's not on the list of supported formats, but still might be worth a try - and always useful to have VLC installed anyway.

Comment: It's a video file. Pelco and other CCTV DVR brands use them. Current VLC does not play it.

Answer (score 0):

Download FFMPEG (there are sources as well as binaries for every system)

then do this: ffmpeg -i myvideo.dsf

It will show you what codecs are in there. After you know which, you can try getting that codec and playing the file.

Comment: no luck, FFMPEG reports "C:\Users\Crom\Downloads\10000004D.dsf: Invalid data found when processing input"

Comment: In that case the file could basically be broken..

Comment: It played fine on the dvr.